# Read multiple files line by line, if time not equal, go to next line in one file (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, loops, iterator

I would like to read multiple files line by line and if the timestamp for the line doesn't fit the other files timestamp, I would like to skip to the next line for that one file, while keeping the other file at the same line until they match.

**Pseudo**

```
read two files
for file0line, file1line in zip(file0, file1):
    # compare time file0line with time file1line
    if file0line < file1line:
        next file0line
        # compare again while file1line stay the same
    if file1line < file0line:
        next file1line
        # compare again while file0line stay the same
    else:
        # they are synced in time
```

**MyCode:**

```
class MyDialect(csv.Dialect):
    strict = True
    skipinitialspace = True
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL
    delimiter = ','
    quotechar = '"'
    lineterminator = '\n'

files = [open(filename) for filename in accelerometers]
for line0, line1 in zip_longest(*files, fillvalue=''):
    b0 = io.StringIO(line0)
    b1 = io.StringIO(line1)
    r0 = csv.reader(b0, MyDialect())
    r1 = csv.reader(b1, MyDialect())
    for i0, i1 in zip(r0, r1):
        time0 = datetime.strptime(i0[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        time1 = datetime.strptime(i1[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        print(time0, time1)
        if time0 != time1:
            if time0 < time1:
                next(line0)
            if time1 < time0:
                next(line1)
        else:
            print(time0, time1)
```

**File example1**

```
Time,Accel-X (g), Accel-Y (g), Accel-Z (g)
2017-03-17 15:41:20.534,0.468750,0.734375,-0.625000
2017-03-17 15:41:20.545,0.218750,0.437500,0.921631
2017-03-17 15:41:20.555,0.281006,0.375000,0.999756
2017-03-17 15:41:20.565,0.343506,0.296875,1.031006
2017-03-17 15:41:20.575,0.328125,0.296875,1.031006
2017-03-17 15:41:20.584,0.328125,0.281250,1.046631
2017-03-17 15:41:20.594,0.296875,0.281006,1.031250
2017-03-17 15:41:20.604,0.281250,0.312256,1.031006
2017-03-17 15:41:20.614,0.250000,0.327881,1.046631
2017-03-17 15:41:20.625,0.249756,0.327881,1.031250
2017-03-17 15:41:20.635,0.250000,0.343506,1.031006
2017-03-17 15:41:20.645,0.249756,0.374756,1.031250
2017-03-17 15:41:20.655,0.265381,0.421631,1.000000
2017-03-17 15:41:20.665,0.281250,0.453125,0.984131
2017-03-17 15:41:20.674,0.296875,0.484375,0.921631
2017-03-17 15:41:20.684,0.312500,0.515625,0.921631
2017-03-17 15:41:20.694,0.328125,0.562500,0.921875
2017-03-17 15:41:20.704,0.359375,0.593750,0.937500
2017-03-17 15:41:20.715,0.375000,0.625000,0.937256
2017-03-17 15:41:20.725,0.406250,0.656250,0.890381
```

**File example2**

```
Time,Accel-X (g), Accel-Y (g), Accel-Z (g)
2017-03-17 15:41:16.514,-0.781250,0.250000,0.500000
2017-03-17 15:41:16.524,-0.468750,-0.234131,0.499756
2017-03-17 15:41:16.534,-0.484131,-0.250000,0.515625
2017-03-17 15:41:16.545,-0.499756,-0.218750,0.484375
2017-03-17 15:41:16.555,-0.515381,-0.203125,0.390625
2017-03-17 15:41:16.565,-0.500000,-0.156250,0.437256
2017-03-17 15:41:16.575,-0.468750,-0.171631,0.468506
2017-03-17 15:41:16.584,-0.452881,-0.156250,0.468506
2017-03-17 15:41:16.594,-0.515381,-0.125000,0.515381
2017-03-17 15:41:16.604,-0.546631,-0.124756,0.515381
2017-03-17 15:41:16.614,-0.546875,-0.156006,0.577881
2017-03-17 15:41:16.625,-0.500000,-0.202881,0.656006
2017-03-17 15:41:16.635,-0.468750,-0.265381,0.687256
2017-03-17 15:41:16.645,-0.452881,-0.312500,0.671875
2017-03-17 15:41:16.655,-0.437500,-0.375000,0.703125
2017-03-17 15:41:16.665,-0.452881,-0.437500,0.718750
2017-03-17 15:41:16.674,-0.437500,-0.500000,0.781250
2017-03-17 15:41:16.684,-0.468750,-0.484131,0.796875
2017-03-17 15:41:16.694,-0.500000,-0.468506,0.796875
2017-03-17 15:41:16.704,-0.500000,-0.421631,0.843750
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to include some input files, and what the output would be for them?

Comment: @MartinEvans I've added some content of one file now, the other file is the same but with other data.

Comment: I was hoping to see a 2nd file example with the required output given those two files, that way we can see where your code is failing and better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Zip will always pick one result from each generator - be it a file, or a CSV reader.

So it is a matter of for each set of lines one have, check the maximum timestap, and if any of the lines has a smaller datetime, read only that line until the timestamp is equal for all the lines.

I made he code for n files, with any of them allowed to be ahead - so it is a bit more complicated at a first sight than your version.  But then, encapsulating it in a generator allows for very simple usage:

```
def getdate(f):
    return datetime.strptime(f, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

def sync_line_reader(*readers, skip_lines=1):
    def get_one_line_of_each(readers):
        lines = []
        for reader in readers:
            lines.append(next(reader))


    try:
        #read first lines, skipping the header:
        for _ in range(skip_lines):
            lines = get_one_line_of_each(*readers)
        while True:
            max_date = max(get_date(f[0]) for f in lines)
            for i, line in enumerate(lines[:]):
                while get_date(line[0]) < max_date:
                    lines[i] = line = next(readers[i])
            yield lines
            lines = get_one_line_of_each(readers)    
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

And you can plug this in your code as:

```
...
files = [open(filename) for filename in accelerometers]
for line0, line1 in zip_longest(*files, fillvalue=''):
    b0 = io.StringIO(line0)
    b1 = io.StringIO(line1)
    r0 = csv.reader(b0, MyDialect())
    r1 = csv.reader(b1, MyDialect())
    for i0, i1 in sync_line_reader((r0, r1)):
         print(get_time(i0[0]), get_time(i1[0]))
```

Comment: I will try it out when I  get to work tomorrow and report back.

Comment: I've went through your code and changed it a bit, but I can't seem to get this line to work: lines[i] = line = next(reader[i]) 
I get the error code: 
    NameError: name 'reader' is not defined

[My code, uploaded to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GwX438kE)

Comment: it should be `readers[i]` , not  `reader[i]` (I am fixing it now)